# How to convert nested array to grayscale images?

Tags: python, autoencoder

I want to take the WM-811k dataset (https://www.kaggle.com/code/ashishpatel26/wm-811k-wafermap/notebook) and autoencode the normal wafers to test how an autoencoder could pick out anomalous wafers.

I'm following this tutorial for MNIST to use an autoencoder and have it working with the MNIST basic example. https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2021/06/complete-guide-on-how-to-use-autoencoders-in-python/

[image]

Instead of the following code:

```
from keras.datasets import mnist
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
```

How can I take LSWMD.pkl and read the nested arrays to images like that of the MNIST dataset?

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_pickle(r'C:\Users\XXXXX\Desktop\googedrive\\LSWMD.pkl')
df['waferMap'][666]
```

Structure of a wafermap array:

```
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        0, 0, 0, 0],...
```

I've tried:

```
df['failureNum']=df.failureType
df['trainTestNum']=df.trianTestLabel
mapping_type={'Center':0,'Donut':1,'Edge-Loc':2,'Edge-Ring':3,'Loc':4,'Random':5,'Scratch':6,'Near-full':7,'none':8}
mapping_traintest={'Training':0,'Test':1}
df=df.replace({'failureNum':mapping_type, 'trainTestNum':mapping_traintest})
df_withpattern = df[(df['failureNum']>=0) & (df['failureNum']<=7)]
df_withpattern = df_withpattern.reset_index()
img = df_withpattern.waferMap[600]
data0 = im.fromarray((img * 255).astype(np.uint8))
data0
```

But all I see is a white circle for every wafer I access (this is #600)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are encountering is with the `PIL` call `.fromarray(img)`. This call makes assumptions about the bit depth of the image you are trying to make. See the optional parameter `'mode'` in the [official documentation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.fromarray).

What it is likely currently doing is assuming from your input int array that you want an 8-bit image, such that the pixel values range from 0 to 255. Since all your values are very small, they will all look approximately black. Change this by changing the `'mode'` parameter and/or scale your integer array such that the maximum integer you expect is scaled to the maximum value of the image's bit depth.

Alternatively, you could use an alternative display method. `matplotlib.pyplot`'s `imshow` method will automatically scale the colormap to the min and max value of your array for maximum visual contrast.